# How to download a GNOME extension manually

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I can't install this extension: [link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/647/icon-area-horizontal-spacing/) because it is outdated. The vast majority of "outdated" extensions work normally after modifying the metadata.json file, so I want to download it anyway, fix it and have a working extension in 2 seconds, but this website doesn't even let me download the zip with extension files, because apparently it thinks that I'm too stupid to add 1 line to the metadata.json file.

Is there a way to force it to give me that file? I think I've seen a way to do this a few months ago by downloading some JSON file, which contains the URL of the zip file, but I don't remember how to do that and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Tried http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/283-gnome-shell-install-extension-command-line-script?

Comment: Can you post an answer summarizing the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it did not work like this back in 2016, but to download an unsupported version of the extension, select a version of Gnome Shell in the dropdown next to "Download". A second drop down will appear with the label "Extension version..." that allows you to select a specific version of the extension. If you do so, a zip file with the extension will start to download.